# Dependency between fields in model using Factoryboy

Tags: django, python-3.x, factory-boy

I have a Django Model that I would like to test using Factoryboy.

The issue here is that the fields depend on each other.

```
class SearchPreferences(models.Model):
    min_age = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True)
    max_age = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True)
```

In this case, `max_age` cannot be smaller then `min_age`.

```
class SearchPreferencesFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    min_age = FuzzyInteger(30, 90)
    max_age = FuzzyInteger(SelfAttribute('min_age'), 100)
```

This is what I have tried to do, which should give me a value for `max_age` between `min_age` and 100, but what happens is a TypeError:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'SelfAttribute' and 'int'
```

This makes sense to me, but I can't really figure out how to get this to work?

Could someone explain what would be the best approach here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a LazyAttribute on your max_age, ie:

```
class SearchPreferencesFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    min_age = FuzzyInteger(30, 90)
    max_age = LazyAttribute(lambda x: FuzzyInteger(x.min_age, 100).fuzz())
```